# Exception in spring rest сервисе

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

Есть сервис:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/generals")
public class Manager {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/request", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> createRequestFilter(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestBody String requestBody
    ) throws IOException {

    }
}
```

отправляю ему POST-запрос с JSON. Тип `application\json`.

Получаю ошибку:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
```

то есть запрос доходит, но падает на попытке закастить Json в `String`.
Пробовал поменять с `String` на `ObjectNode` - все завелось.
Но, хотелось бы разобраться в чем дело.

Comment: Какой запрос приходит на этот URL ? Есть предположение, что вы отправляете запрос: `TestString` , а спрингу надо `"TestString"`

Comment: {
"user": {
"bithday": "2016-09-12T08:03:13+00:00"
},

Comment: о как. Тогда String не подойдет. Сейчас напишу в ответ. А вы добавье пример запроса в Ваш вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Можете создать отдельный граф классов, описывающий входные параметры:

```
public class RootElement {

    private User;

    //getters and setters
}

public class User {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddd'T'hh:mm:ss")
    private Date birthday;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Поменяйте в Вашем контроллере:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> createRequestFilter(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestBody RootElement requestBody
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос разрешился удалением интерсептора, добавленного по случайности в спринг-контекст. Он же и преобразовывал приходящий боди.